# Why does change in the model not reflect in child views?

Tags: swiftui, foreach

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var cntrl=ContentViewController2()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ItemsDisplay(items: cntrl.model.items, handler: cntrl.updateItem)
        }
    }
    
}

struct ItemsDisplay:View {
    
    let items:[SubItem]
    let handler:(SubItem)->Void
    
    init(items: [SubItem], handler: @escaping (SubItem) -> Void) {
        self.items = items
        self.handler = handler
        
        print("init of ItemsDisplay")
        for item in items {
            print("\(item.id) \(item.value)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) {item in
                ItemDisplay(item: item, handler: handler)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDisplay:View {
    
    let item:SubItem
    let handler:(SubItem)->Void
    
    init(item: SubItem, handler: @escaping (SubItem) -> Void) {
        self.item = item
        self.handler = handler
        print("init of ItemDisplay: \(item.value)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(item.id)")
            Text("\(item.value)")
        }
        .padding(.all)
        .border(.black, width:5)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("tapped")
            handler(item)
        }
    }
}

struct SubItem:Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: SubItem, rhs: SubItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let id:String
    var value:Int
    
    mutating func changeValue(_ newval:Int) {
        print("changing value to: \(newval)")
        value=newval
    }
}

struct ContentViewModel2 {
    var items:[SubItem]
    
    
    mutating func updateItem(_ item:SubItem) {
        if let i=items.firstIndex(of: item) {
            let newValue=item.value+1
            print("newValue for item: \(item.id) should be: \(newValue)")
            items[i].changeValue(newValue)
            print("newValue of item: \(items[i].id) is: \(items[i].value)")
        }
    }
    
}

class ContentViewController2:ObservableObject {
    @Published var model:ContentViewModel2
    
    init() {
        model=ContentViewModel2(items: [SubItem(id: "box1", value: 1), SubItem(id: "box10", value: 10)])
    }
    
    func updateItem(_ item:SubItem) {
        if let i=model.items.firstIndex(of: item) {
            print("updating: \(item.id)")
            model.updateItem(item)
        }
//        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

The code above creates a VStack of 2 SubItem structs as a box with a name and a number. When the box is clicked, the value of the number displayed should increment by 1 by calling a handler of the controller that holds the "source of truth" in @Published var model.

The problem is that the change in value does not show.

I init each View to see what values are passed. It seems to work all the way down to ItemsDisplay:View.
But it seems that the body of this View is not called, thus the ItemDisplay:View never gets to display the new value.

I don't understand why when the init is called with items that have changed correctly, it's body is not called.

Any ideas?

When I click on the box1, this prints out:

tapped
updating: box1
newValue for item: box1 should be: 2
changing value to: 2
newValue of item: box1 is: 2
init of ItemsDisplay
box1 2
box10 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
static func == (lhs: SubItem, rhs: SubItem) -> Bool {
     lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Is telling SwiftUI to only reload views when the `id` changes.

Remove it.

Keep the original implementation of `Equatable`

SwiftUI is dependent on Equatable, Identifiable and Hashable. Don’t override default implementations unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Hello Iorem and thank you very much for your solution. I did make it Equatable to be able to use the "items.firstIndex(of: item)" instead of firstIndex(where: " and had no idea  it would affect me in this way. I spent at least 2h trying to find the reason why it was not working. Almost feel like buying you a beer :) Thanks again.

Comment: Hello Iorem, I have come along a similar problem when using navigationstack and programatically navigating. I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417899/model-change-not-reflected-if-in-navigationstack. any idea where the problem might be this time? thank you in advance. Libor